# Webpack, Angular2 rebuild optimization

Tags: performance, angular, bundle, webpack

I'm trying to compile Angular2 with webpack; here is my setup: I have a vendor.ts file where I have:

```
import 'es6-shim/es6-shim.min';
import 'reflect-metadata/Reflect.js';
import 'zone.js/dist/zone';

import '@angular/platform-browser';
import '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import '@angular/core';
import '@angular/common';
import '@angular/http';
import '@angular/router-deprecated';
```

My `webpack.config.js`:

```
"use strict";
let path = require('path');
let webpack = require("webpack");
let CommonsChunkPlugin = webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin;
let ProvidePlugin = webpack.ProvidePlugin;
let UglifyJsPlugin = webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin;

module.exports = {
    devtool: 'source-map',
    debug: true, // set false in production
    cache: true,
    entry: {
        vendor: './app/vendor.ts',
        app: './app/main.ts'
    },
    output: {
        filename: './public/assets/js/[name].js'
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(true),
        new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({name: 'vendor', filename: './public/assets/js/vendor.js', minChunks: Infinity}),
        new UglifyJsPlugin({
            compress: {
                warnings: false
            }
        })
    ],
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.ts$/,
                loader: 'ts-loader',
                query: {
                    'ignoreDiagnostics': [
                        2403, // 2403 -> Subsequent variable declarations
                        2300, // 2300 -> Duplicate identifier
                        2374, // 2374 -> Duplicate number index signature
                        2375 // 2375 -> Duplicate string index signature
                    ]
                },
                exclude: [/\.(spec|e2e)\.ts$/, /node_modules\/(?!(ng2-.+))/]
            }
        ]
    },

    resolve: {
        extensions: ["", ".ts", ".js"]
    }
};
```

So, all is fine, webpack is compiling the stuff, but it's too slow. It's taking 15089ms. I'm planning to add this as a gulp task but this won't work, I have to wait like 3-5 seconds for each save. Is it possible to have a setup where if the chunks don't change, to prevent compilation? This would improve the performance a lot. Thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to disable `webpack.optimize.*` plugins, switch `devtool` to `eval` and add `transpileOnly: true` to `ts-loader` query.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This improved the preformance a litle bit, but still not enough. Is still quite slow and the files now are too big. I think I have to get rid of webpack and do evrithing with gulp. Then I think, I would have more control of what to compile. Because I really need the vendors to be compiled only when the server is started. And to recompile only the app.js on changes in app dir.

Comment: it should be fast, enable webpack watch mode: `watch: true`